# Merge data from two websites into a PDF using ColdFusion

Tags: pdf, coldfusion, merge, webserver, edit

I have a project where a web page has a form where the user enters some information and then hits a button which uses this information (e.g. ZIP code) as part of a query to dynamically exports the results as a PDF or XLS file.  The data I am querying is housed in an Oracle database on Server A.

Server A is controlled by a different contractor who is agnostic to our project (not antagonistic but not especially helpful).  This other contractor controls the ColdFusion, Oracle database and Server A.

It turns out we now have updated information that is housed on Server B that the client wants to include in the PDF/XLS file.  Server B is under **my** control but the data is in a Geographic Information System (GIS).  Server B's data will be set up to be served out as a REST service which can accept input from Server A and spit out the answer.  I can output the data in JSON format, XLS, PDF (and maybe CSV but I need to check).   I cannot put the data (or software) onto Server A nor dump the contents into the Oracle database.

My question is this:

> What techniques can I employ to successfully dynamically incorporate my updated data into this PDF ?

I am not sure if the client has Adobe LifeCycle (still checking) so I would like to have a solution that does not use this product.

I have poked around the internet and have found some resources (such as [Populate_And_Merge_Multiple_PDF_Forms](http://cfpdf.blogspot.com/2008/04/populate-and-merge-multiple-pdf-forms.html) but I am still looking for some resources that describe a solution.

Many Thanks !

Comment: if the pdf/xls is being generated dynamically, is it possible to send them json and have them incorporate it into the documents as they are being created or does your data have to get crammed in like an afterthought?

Comment: Hi Travis,  My hope is that is exactly what I can do.  Is that a technically simple process ?

Comment: yeah, writing a remote cfc with functions like serializejson and your function returntype = json. Making a light weight web service is easy.  Are you writing the code for 'server a' too? If not it would be up to them to consume your service and include your data.

Comment: Hi Travis,  they write the code for 'Server A' but I will let them know the JSON format so I *think* it will work.  Can you submit an answer (with perhaps a link) and I can give you credit ?

Answer (score 1):

Creating a simple web service in ColdFusion is pretty straight forward.  To consume your service the other company will use CFHTTP or their technology's equivalent.

In your CFC, make sure your function's `access` attribute is set to `remote`. Doing so will allow your function to be accessed from an outside source.

> remote: available to a locally or remotely executing page or component
>   method, or a remote client through a URL, Flash, or a web service. To
>   publish the function as a web service, this option is required.

Also, specify your `returnformat` attribute to be `JSON`

> The format in which to return values to a remote caller. This
>   attribute has no effect on values returned to a local caller. json:
>   serialize the return value into JSON format before returning it
>   remotely

I have also used `returnformat` of `plain` to prevent any other formatting by ColdFusion so if you wanted to create a custom output such as a simple list of values, use plain.

> plain: ensure that the return value is a type that ColdFusion can
>   convert directly to a string, and return the string value without
>   serialization. Valid types include all simple types, such as numbers,
>   and XML objects. If the return value is a complex type, such as an
>   array, or a binary value, ColdFusion generates an error. If you
>   specify a returntype attribute, its value must be any, boolean, date,
>   guid, numeric, string, uuid, variablename, or XML; otherwise,
>   ColdFusion generates an error.

Sources:

[CFFunction](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7f5c.html)